# Extract a proper content from the url using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm looking how I can extract the content of news articles like CNN or NewYork times using `Jsoup`.

In fact I had tried the following code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://edition.cnn.com/2013/11/10/world/asia/philippines-typhoon-haiyan/index.html").get();

Element contents = document.select("#content").first();

System.out.println(contents.html()); 

System.out.println(contents.text());
```

I had received this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.clearforest.Test.main(Test.java:36)
```

Have you an idea please How I can extract a proper text from articles.

Comment: You have not provided enough information about what the problem is. The exception message clearly says there is an NPE at line 36 in our class. Perhaps check that out or post it here?

Answer (score 1):

Your `contents Element` is null after the `select` call - the selector you specified returns no matches in the document downloaded from CNN - try something like `document.select("div.cnn_strycntntlft")` which returns the story div contents.